# python RESTでGETしたBodyの内容を変数に代入する方法

Tags: python

RESTでGETすると以下のような結果をJSONで受信します。
`"params"` 内にある `result1` の `"abcde"` と、 `result2` の `"efghi"` を変数に代入したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

```js
{
  "code": null,
  "reason": null,
  "params": {
    "result1": "abcde",
    "result2": "efghi"
  },
  "result": true,
  "error": null
}
```

どなたか方法をご指導ねがえますでしょうか。

Comment: 例えば`requests`モジュールを使って`resp=requests.get()`した場合結果は`resp.json()`で取得できて、値はlistまたはdictになっています。あとは通常の操作で値を変更するだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
自分もdictでとれることに気が付きました。

Answer (score 2):

例えばrequestsモジュールを使ってresp=requests.get()した場合結果はresp.json()で取得できて、値はlistまたはdictになっています。あとは通常の操作で値を変更するだけです。

**サンプルコード**

```
import requests

# カレントディレクトリに下記コマンドでtest.jsonを配置し、簡易サーバを立てた場合の例
# > python -m http.server 8000

url = "http://localhost:8000/test.json" 
resp = requests.get(url)
params = resp.json()["params"]
result1 = params["result1"]
result2 = params["result2"]

print(result1, result2)
#abcde efghi
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @KenjiNoguchi さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20058/python-rest%e3%81%a7get%e3%81%97%e3%81%9fbody%e3%81%ae%e5%86%85%e5%ae%b9%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ab%e4%bb%a3%e5%85%a5%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment18760_20058)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>